# New freebsd setup partitioning

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, freebsd, pata

I am setting up a new server for my home network that is going to run freebsd. I have three hard disks installed, one is 3GB, one 20GB, and one 40GB.

The disks are on an IDE bus with the 3GB drive as primary master (thus being the boot drive), the 40GB disk as primary slave, CD drive as secondary master, and the 20GB disk as secondary slave.

The 40GB drive will have its own mountpoint and is not a problem. However, I want to use the 3GB drive as a boot disk (with /boot and the like) and have the 20GB drive hold the main / partition and installation. If I am to do this, what should my partitions look like? What do I need to tell the installer for this setup to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the OS is installed under `/usr`. A classic strategy would be to specify `/usr` as a separately mounted filesystem from one of your larger disks. This is easily accomplished using the *Partition Editor* in the *Guided* installation.